# usable ram is less than actual in dual channel

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have an acer aspire 5742zg-p613g32mnkk

cpu: p6100 Pentium dual core

ram: 3gb 1066 MHz

hdd:300 ahci

gpu: radeon 5470 512 mb

in properties of computer or system information usable ram is 2.54 of 3.

I've tested various ways to fix this. I've updated my bios and I configured max ram in Msconfig, but ram not fixed. I've ejected each one of ram modules, in single channel mode ram showed property. I wonder if you friends help me fix the problem because my pc speed is low even in gam C&C Generals zero hour. tnx